# What is an AjaxAdapter and what is query()?

Tags: javascript

I have a code:

```
req = new AjaxAdapter;
req.dataType = 'json';

return req.query('GET', url, request, function(responseServer, status, xhr) {
        var json;
        json = responseServer.data;
        return response(json);
    }, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var exception;
        exception = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
        return showError(exception);
    });
```

And I don't understand it. So what is the `query()` function? I can't find it in the jQuery documentation. See in my example that this function has 5 parameters:

- get
- url
- request
- function which return data (response)
- function which is call when is error

What is request? Where I can found documentation of the `query()` function?

Comment: I think the question is: what is AjaxAdapter? Can you find the definition of AjaxAdapter?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/wireit/psZEjY3L3Go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't jQuery. As for what the `query` method does, look at its signature:

```
req.query( 'GET', url, request, function( responseServer, status, xhr )
```

It takes the post-type as the first parameter, a URL as the second, your request data as the third, and a callback function when the request completes.

Your callback returns the server's response, a status code indicating the type of response, as well as the XHR object the query method used to issue the request.

Answer (score 0):

The `query` function doesn't exist in jQuery

You must be using another library

Answer (score 0):

This is not jquery, but you could try

```
console.log(AjaxAdapter.query)
```

to see what the function does

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery $.ajax instead

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {id : menuId},
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $("#log").html( msg );
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Comment: While perhaps a valid *alternative*, it doesn't answer the question itself.